# Newbie running full node (Bitcoin Core): Commands to import wallet with passphrase from external USB stick? And how to sweep paper wallet?

Tags: wallet.dat, paper-wallet, private-key-import, command-line-options

I need help with:

- Which console commands (Linux) to use to import external USB stick wallet (with passphrase) created by an earlier version of (Linux) Bitcoin Core?
- How to sweep paper wallet (with passphrase)?

For the first time, I want to transfer from a Bitcoin Core wallet to an exchange to sell.

Answer (score 0):

At the /home/user/.bitcoin directory, replace the wallet name directory with the one to copy.

Make a burner wallet to get some understanding, then replace the burner wallet with the one you want.